# Create Virtual X session

Tags: x11

Is there a way to create multiple X sessions on a machine (not using VNC)?
I'm looking to create a virtual or secondary X session that has multiple displays and monitors as defined by my xorg.conf.

Answer (score 1):

At the lowest level, starting a second X server is as simple as launching the `X` program with a display name as an argument. Your first one will have the display name `:0` so to avoid conflicting with it:

```
X :1
```

(you'd want to do that from a text console, not from inside an existing X session).

It will start itself on the next available VT, so if you switch to your first X server with Alt+F7, the second one will be reachable with Alt+F8.

That will just be a server though, nothing will be running on it so it'll be a blank screen with a mouse cursor. You can direct programs to run on it with the `DISPLAY` environment variable. Starting a window manager should be enough to get you a usable session:

```
DISPLAY=:1 twm &
```

If you're not interested in the low-level stuff and you want something more like your normal login session, you can try the `startx` tool. It takes server options after a `--` so you can run

```
startx -- :1 &
```

If you want a second X server to start at boot time and show a login screen, add it to your `xdm` (or other `*dm`) configuration. For xdm, this would be `/etc/X11/xdm/Xservers`